# How do I find out the duration of video without mediaPlayer?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, duration, mediametadataretriever

Actually I'm trying to find out the `duration of video from URl` but it throws *null pointer exception*

```
try{
    File file = new File("http://84.--.--.--:8--9/"+filename);
    if ( file.toString().endsWith(".jpg")) {
            //photo
        } else if (file.toString().endsWith(".mp4")) {
            //video
            long mills = MediaPlayer.create(UploadFileService.this, Uri.parse(file.getAbsolutePath().toString())).getDuration();                                
            Log.d("duration", "" + mills);
        }                        
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();

retriever.setDataSource(intent.getStringExtra("fileName"));
String time = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
int VideoDuration = Integer.parseInt(time);// This will give time in millesecond
```

Comment: Got java.lang.IllegalArgumentException on setdataSource

Comment: You have to give filename on the setDataSource.What you are giving??

Comment: May be it will be throwing "file not found exception" as this file doesn't exist

Comment: I have seen your comment at rscnt.You are doing this :setDataSource(UploadService.this, Uri.parse(filename.toString())); I think so you are downloading file from the network.So, do this :       setDataSource(new File(Uri.parse(filename.toString()));

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - The constructor File(Uri) is undefined
 - The method setDataSource(String) in the type MediaMetadataRetriever is not applicable for the 
  arguments (File)

Answer (score 1):

Use [FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever):

```
import wseemann.media.FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever;

...

FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();

retriever.setDataSource("some URL");
String time = retriever.extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
int duration = Integer.parseInt(time);
retriever.release();
```

Comment: That's why the library provides gradle variants for each architecture. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

You cloud try using the class MediaMetadataRetriever, you just need to set a datasource to an instace of it, then check for the information you're looking for.

- [MediaMetadataRetriever](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html), [setDataSource()](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/media/java/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.java#L93)

Comment: Sir I have used this it : it throws java illegal exception.
here is my code:
 MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        retriever.setDataSource(UploadFileService.this, Uri.parse(file.toString()));
        String time = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
        long timeInmillisec = Long.parseLong( time );

Answer (score 0):

You should try this,
I hope this works.

```
MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
retriever.setDataSource(File.getPath()); // Enter Full File Path Here
String time = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
long timeInmillisec = Long.parseLong(time); // You will get time in milliseconds
```